# Does pressing down on the analog sticks increase the likelyhood of stick drift?

Tags: ps4, controllers, xbox-one

Just got a new controller that I saved up for almost a year and I'd like to prolong it's lifespan. I forgot where I read/heard this, but I recall someone saying how pressing down on the analog sticks L3/R3 (and whatever Xbox's equivalent is) makes it more likely to drift. How true is this?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.

The reason why Stick Drift happens is because the copper circle used to measure the position of the Analog Stick ends up damaging the carbon part due to friction. This causes incorrect and unreliable measurements of the analog's position.

You can see the inside of the analog sticks used in the DualSense here (also used in DualShock 4, Xbox One, Xbox One Elite and Xbox Series X|S):

[image]

Ill recommend reading the [Here’s Why PS5 Joysticks Drift (and Why They’ll Only Get Worse)](https://www.ifixit.com/News/48944/heres-why-ps5-joysticks-drift-and-why-theyll-only-get-worse) article from iFixit